# how to insert one json array string to another json object android

Tags: java, json, arraylist

i create two json string using GSON now i want to insert one json string to another but i don't understand how to I achieve this

json string 1

```
 {"floors":[{"coveredArea":"200","floorId":"12","uploaded":false,"id":1},{"coveredArea":"200","floorId":"12","uploaded":false,"id":5}]}
```

json String 2

```
"surveys":[{"UId":"2","occupier": "rent","propertyId": "3","formId":1605250886166,"isSubmitted":false,"id":1}]}
```

but i want to this like this result

```
{
"surveys": [{
    "propertyId": "3",
    "UId": "161",
    "occupier": "rent",
    "formId": 1605250886166,
    "isSubmitted": true,
    
    "floor": [{
            "floorId": "200",
            "coveredArea": "200"
        },
        {
            "floorId": "200",
            "coveredArea": "200"
        }
    ]
}]
```

}

Comment: You can create a `List<Floor> floors;` in Survey class and use a setter to set this floors list in servery object.

Comment: m using sugarorm i have created two table Floor and Surveys  when i set it just create survey json not floor